# Facebook's Graph API manage_pages shows only applications?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get a list of the application user's pages after authenticating them, but I am just getting a list of applications associated with the account.

After authentication (with the manage_pages permission set) I'm sending to the following URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=$realToken

What's returned though, is solely applications. The account I'm testing with should have nearly 20 pages associated with it.

Here's some of my code...

```
$fetchToken = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=$appid&redirect_uri=$redirect&scope=offline_access,manage_pages&client_secret=$appSecret&code=".$_GET['code'];

$token = file_get_contents($fetchToken);

...

$pages = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=$realToken");
```

Comment: Code looks ok.. Only doubt is if you have manage_pages permission in your token. Did you see manage pages permission on facebook web page along with allow button.

Comment: Didn't even think to look for it. I'll remove the app and reapprove it - maybe that'll fix it.

Comment: Yep, that did it Satish!